# Re-adding users profile into new DC/AD server

Tags: domain, directory, controller

Need some advice. It is related with my question last week.
"Could I create new DC/AD from fresh installation in new machine then I do adding all users information (username and password) based on users PC and Laptop profile desktop? (by collecting one by one from users PC/Laptop) and how to automatically add security right based on users profile in their Laptop/PC?.

After re-adding all user profile into new machine server, does it will be allowed by the win server system when login into domain"

Thanks.